# Need to total up selections

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google scripting and am trying to create an order form that totals on a new sheet. I found some tutorials that have gotten me this far.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gABaW1qaJyaL1k4QSh0nqkJ7uCCyc8NmL02wcn1klpA/edit?usp=sharing

The current script allows styles and color/size options to be populated on the Ranges sheet that then is auto-populated on the Order Form sheet based on their selection. Since the styles and color/size options can change I need a script to create the Order Totals sheet which will contain the totals for each Style, Color/Size option that is populated on the Order Form sheet.

With the sample data that I have in the Order form the Order Totals would look like:

```
Style, Color/Size, Quantity
=
Adult Unisex, Grey - Small, 3
-
Youth, Grey - Large, 1
-
Youth, Grey - X-Large, 3
-
Adult Unisex, Grey - Medium, 1
-
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this somehow with the Sheets built-in functions, but here is an Apps Script solution that is working for me on the sheet you provided.
This is a general solution for *n* columns of item descriptors before a final quantity column.

```js
/**
 * @param {string} A1RangeString - e.g. "A1:C"
 * @returns {string[][]} suitable for Range.setValues
 */
function getOrderTotals(A1RangeString) {
  var orders = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Order Form")
    .getRange(A1RangeString).getValues().filter(function (row) {
      return row[0]; // i.e. it's not blank
    });
  var totals = orders.reduce(readOrders, {});
  return writeTotals(totals);
}

/**
 * @param {obj} orderBook - nested dictionary, see readOrders
 * @returns {string[][]} for use with Range.setValues
 */
function writeTotals(orderBook) {
  if (typeof orderBook === "number") {
    return [orderBook];
  }
  var items = [];
  Object.keys(orderBook).forEach(function(key) {
    var result = writeTotals(orderBook[key]);
    result.forEach(function (description) {
      items.push([key].concat(description));
    });
  });
  return items;
}

/**
 * readOrders is a callback for Array.prototype.reduce
 * @param {obj} orderBook - a nested dictionary
 * @param {row} string[]
 */
function readOrders(orderBook, row) {
  var item = orderBook;
  for (var i = 0; i < row.length - 2; ++i) {
    if (! item[row[i]]) {
      item[row[i]] = {};
    }
    item = item[row[i]];
  }
  if (! item[row[row.length - 2]]) {
    item[row[row.length - 2]] = row[row.length - 1];
  } else {
    item[row[row.length - 2]] += row[row.length - 1];
  }
  return orderBook;
}

function onEdit() {
  var orders = getOrderTotals("C3:E");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Order Totals")
    .getRange(1, 1, orders.length, orders[0].length)
    .setValues(orders);
  // other onEdit stuff continues below
}
```

Comment: That is working. So if I add more Styles across on the Ranges sheet the only thing I need to do in the script is change the .getRange("C3:E") to how ever many more columns I use, correct?

Comment: @JamesTX10 now the answer supports a general solution for an arbitrary length of columns, the original answer did not.  Now you can adjust the range for whatever column width you need, provided the last column is the quantity column.

Comment: Your first answer worked better for me. When I pasted this code in then sometimes the Order form script would not always work like something was hung in the back ground

Comment: @JamesTX10 - I'm sorry to hear that.  Is there a particular input or configuration that seems to hang it up?  It's still working for me...

Comment: I read through the code on your first answer some more and I think you built that to do what I needed. I would not add columns on the Order Form tab but on the Ranges tab. It looks like your code does not care about the ranges tab which means it will work no matter how many styles are added since it only looks at the Order Form tab. Right?